# Getting error when querying iceberg table via Spark thrift server using beeline client?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to query iceberg table (External table with data in S3 & Metadata in Hivemetastore) using spark thrift server coming as part of Spark. I am able to query non iceberg tables but when I query iceberg table I am getting below error. Can we not query iceberg table via spark thrift server?

Version details

- Spark - 3.2.1
- Scala - 2.12.15
- Iceberg spark library  - [iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12](https://iceberg.apache.org/multi-engine-support/)
- I have added other S3 , AWS dependency jars from maven and added in spark jars folder.

I have started the thrift server with following command

```
start-thriftserver.sh \
--hiveconf hive.metastore.uris=thrift://$ip:$port \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=$key \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=$secret \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.uri=thrift://$ip:$port \
--conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.type=hive \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.io-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO \
--conf iceberg.engine.hive.enabled=true \
```

Error in beeline when querying iceberg table `select count(*) from $table_name`

```
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServerErrors$.runningQueryError(HiveThriftServerErrors.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:325)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.$anonfun$run$2(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:230)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkOperation.withLocalProperties(SparkOperation.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkOperation.withLocalProperties$(SparkOperation.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.withLocalProperties(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:225)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:239)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getNumPartitions(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.$anonfun$submitShuffleJob$1(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.submitShuffleJob(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.submitShuffleJob$(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.submitShuffleJob(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.shuffleFuture$lzycompute(QueryStageExec.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.shuffleFuture(QueryStageExec.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.doMaterialize(QueryStageExec.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExec.materialize(QueryStageExec.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$5(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$5$adapted(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:254)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.getFinalPhysicalPlan(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:300)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        ... 75 more (state=,code=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your configuration, it looks like you’re trying to use a catalog named `iceberg_catalog`, but it’s being configured as Iceberg’s `SparkSessionCatalog`.

However, `SparkSessionCatalog` is reserved for the default catalog that Spark uses, which allows that catalog to be used with both Iceberg tables and other formats.

The session catalog must be named `spark_catalog`. This is a requirement imposed by Spark.

So you need to either use `org.apache.iceberg.SparkCatalog` with your current configuration of a separate catalog named `iceberg_catalog` (where the name is up to you), or if you want to override the default catalog so that Iceberg tables and non-Iceberg tables can live within one catalog, you’d need to change the catalog name to `spark_catalog` and keep your current configuration.

Refer to the docs on [adding catalogs](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/getting-started/#adding-catalogs). In the configuration used there the session catalog, `spark_catalog`, is overridden and then there is also a catalog named `local` that is distinct and can only have Iceberg tables.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Bendickson : I renamed my catalog name to spark_catalog. Now That error is gone and new exception which says class not found is showing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class software.amazon.awssdk.regions.internal.util.EC2MetadataUtils
        at software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.InstanceProfileRegionProvider.tryDetectRegion(InstanceProfileRegionProvider.java:68)
        at 
```
I am running locally seems like it is trying some EC2 util classes to get region information.

Comment: This has been fixed by downloading each and every jars from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk

Comment: To keep it simple, the only two jars you need from software.amazon.awssdk are bundle and url-connection-client. We recommend version 2.17.131 but you’re free to use whatever versions you need or just standalone jars (eg S3, DynamoDB) if you’d like to be slimmer than the bundle itself. See https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/aws/#spark - Exact version the code was compiled against can be pulled from Iceberg’s `versions.props` file (master at time of writing is here https://github.com/apache/iceberg/blob/c9442f1c0f0524b7ca5ac3ccbb927cc80b764239/versions.props#L27)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table via Spark/Beeline and you can see that table, but not the table that exist within Hive, that typically means Spark isn't configured to use Hive metastore.

In Spark 1.6, by default the Thrift server runs in multi-session mode. Which means each JDBC/ODBC connection owns a copy of their own SQL configuration and temporary function registry. Cached tables are still shared. You are registering a temp table and so in order to see the temp table, you need to run the Thrift server in single-session mode. In spark-default.conf set spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession to true. When you call for an instance of the Thrift server in you code, it should start up in single session mode. When you initialize and register the temp table, it should show up when you connect and issue show tables command. You can create a permanent table in which case it should show up in multi session mode and from Hive (You have the code to do that but it's commented out).
Under /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf on the sandbox:

```
[root@sandbox conf]# cat hive-site.xml 
  <configuration> 
    <property> 
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name> 
      <value>thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083</value> 
    </property> 
  </configuration>
```